# dplyr: using column created by mutate in the mutation itself

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 5,427 x 3
    cond desired   inc
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  <NA>       0     0
 2  <NA>       5     5
 3     X      10     5
 4     X       7     7
 5  <NA>      16    16
 6  <NA>      21     5
 7  <NA>      26     5
 8  <NA>      31     5
 9     X      37     6
10  <NA>       5     5
```

this already includes my desired output. What I want to do is sum up the values of `inc`, but reset the sum if there is an `X` in the `cond`-column of the previous row. So for example in row `9` I'd take the `desired`-value from the previous row (31) and add the `inc`-value from row `9` (6) which gives 37. And in row `5` I'd just take the `inc`-value because the `cond`-column of the previous row was `X`. I solved this using a loop, but I'd like to use a vectorized solution. So far I got this:

```
df$test <- 0
df <- df %>% mutate(test = ifelse(is.na(lag(df$cond)), lag(test) + inc, inc))
```

If I run the second line once I get this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 5,427 x 4
    cond desired   inc  test
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  <NA>       0     0    NA
 2  <NA>       5     5     5
 3     X      10     5     5
 4     X       7     7     7
 5  <NA>      16    16    16
 6  <NA>      21     5     5
 7  <NA>      26     5     5
 8  <NA>      31     5     5
 9     X      37     6     6
10  <NA>       5     5     5
```

After the second run it looks like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 5,427 x 4
    cond desired   inc  test
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  <NA>       0     0    NA
 2  <NA>       5     5    NA
 3     X      10     5    10
 4     X       7     7     7
 5  <NA>      16    16    16
 6  <NA>      21     5    21
 7  <NA>      26     5    10
 8  <NA>      31     5    10
 9     X      37     6    11
10  <NA>       5     5     5
# ... with 5,417 more rows
```

Third time:

```
> df
# A tibble: 5,427 x 4
    cond desired   inc  test
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  <NA>       0     0    NA
 2  <NA>       5     5    NA
 3     X      10     5    NA
 4     X       7     7     7
 5  <NA>      16    16    16
 6  <NA>      21     5    21
 7  <NA>      26     5    26
 8  <NA>      31     5    15
 9     X      37     6    16
10  <NA>       5     5     5
```

Then, after the fifth time:

```
> df
# A tibble: 5,427 x 4
    cond desired   inc  test
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  <NA>       0     0    NA
 2  <NA>       5     5    NA
 3     X      10     5    NA
 4     X       7     7     7
 5  <NA>      16    16    16
 6  <NA>      21     5    21
 7  <NA>      26     5    26
 8  <NA>      31     5    31
 9     X      37     6    37
10  <NA>       5     5     5
```

I'm using the column I'm creating with mutate in the mutate-command itself and I guess that is causing this behaviour/problem. Is there any way to get to my desired result? Thanks in advance!

the dataframe:

```
structure(list(cond = c(NA, NA, "X", "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, "X", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "X", NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, "X", "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", "X", NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "X", NA, "X", 
NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "X", NA, NA, NA), desired = c(0, 5, 10, 7, 16, 21, 26, 
31, 37, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 5, 10, 15, 20, 
30, 7, 15, 21, 25, 40, 45, 55, 12, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 
55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 5, 10, 15, 20, 22, 30, 35, 45, 50, 55, 60, 
65, 70, 75, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 5, 7, 10, 2, 7, 12, 
17, 22, 27, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 38, 4, 7, 12, 17, 22, 
27, 32, 37, 39, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 5, 10, 15, 
20, 25, 30, 35, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 5, 10, 
15, 20, 2, 10, 15, 20, 25, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 
5, 8, 12, 5, 10, 14, 19, 24, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 28, 33, 38, 5, 11, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 
35, 40, 45, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 5, 5, 10, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 
30, 35, 40, 45, 5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 34, 39, 
44, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 5, 10, 15, 20, 
25, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 29, 5, 10, 15, 20, 23, 25, 30, 35, 40, 
5, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 5, 10, 15, 20, 
25, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 58, 71, 76, 81, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 
10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 5, 
10, 15), inc = c(0, 5, 5, 7, 16, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 7, 8, 6, 4, 15, 5, 10, 12, 8, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 8, 5, 10, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 13, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 12, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 13, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), .Names = c("cond", 
"desired", "inc"), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The `cond` column is `x` even in row `9`. Hence, per rule stated by you the sum should set there as well. Why row `9` is different from row `3` or `4`?

Comment: the X affects the next row, so the X in row 9 resets the sum and in row 10 inc becomes the sum. The same goes for row 3 and 4: in the rows 4 and 5 desired is the same as inc of that row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To arrive at your desired output, we must first create a grouping column that resets every time the previous row is equal to `X`. For this we use `row_number()` in combination with `zoo::na.locf()`. Then we can simply use `cumsum()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% group_by(grp = na.locf(row_number(cond), 
                              fromLast = TRUE, 
                              na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(test = cumsum(inc))
#    cond desired   inc   grp  test
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1  <NA>       0     0     1     0
# 2  <NA>       5     5     1     5
# 3     X      10     5     1    10
# 4     X       7     7     2     7
# 5  <NA>      16    16     3    16
# 6  <NA>      21     5     3    21
# 7  <NA>      26     5     3    26
# 8  <NA>      31     5     3    31
# 9     X      37     6     3    37
#10  <NA>       5     5     4     5
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example using the `ave()` function and the df structure from above. I'm showing all the steps for clarity but these could be reduced if needed.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(prevcond = lag(cond)) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(is.na(prevcond) | prevcond !='X', 0, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(counter = cumsum(flag)) %>% 
  mutate(desired2 = ave(inc, counter, FUN = cumsum))
```